# send a text message via .net

Tags: c#, .net, sms

All:  Are there any free solutions out there for sending text messages (SMS) via .net?  (maybe a web service or something?).

**EDIT**

What I'm really looking for is a reference for a reputable online service that I can use for sending SMS messages.  Has anyone out there used such a service, and if so, can you give me a recommendation/warning?

**EDIT**

*(first the disclaimer:  I'm not in any way associated with this company, I'm just posting back what I found, in case anyone else out there is looking)*

An update:  I ended up going with www.clickatel.com  My work was for a technology exploration and demo project,and I could buy credits on that system cheap.  In my case, I started out using their REST API.  I had problems with that api (sometimes the commands would timeout).  So I switched to the web service API (SOAP)  It worked very well for me.

Comment: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Sending_SMS_using_Net.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Sending_SMS_using_Net.aspx) this is an article that explains how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Most accept email but it is vendor specific.