# How to send sms messages from computer using C#?

Tags: c#, sms, sms-gateway

I want to make an app that allows someone to text from their computer. After researching email to sms gateways, I have found that there is no good way to automatically find the receivers carrier, which makes it impossible to send them a text unless they tell you their carrier.

Is there any way to send a text without an email-sms gateway, perhaps with a bluetooth connection to the phone, or (hopefully) something much less complex than that?

If not, is there any way to automatically detect a persons carrier based on their phone number?

**Update:** I don't want to pay for anything, or use any website or service. I only want to use carrier-provided gateways, if required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send a text message via .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580764/send-a-text-message-via-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can, one of the possible method is by using the GSM Comm library.
The library is [here](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

For implementation details of GSMComm lib, please refer to this question:
[Sending SMS Through GSMCOMM library of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522442/sending-sms-through-gsmcomm-library-of-c-sharp)

Comment: Telling someone a question is a duplicate question, is not an answer. You could have said that in a comment or mark the question as duplicate. But I wont downvote since you are new.

Comment: This answer is might be kind of helpful, but it's probably the most complicated answer you could possibly give. Also, I don't believe that this question is a duplicate of that at all. That question stems from a possible answer for my question, but they in no way ask the same thing, or have the same answer.

Comment: Hi @CodingYoshi I was trying to answer the question by simply stated that it is possible to send SMS without some web service or sms gateway using C#.

Comment: Hi @Evan, I see your point. Perhaps I should rephrase my answer. Thanks you CodingYoshi and Evan for pointing out my error.